# Transform X509Certificate Subject DN to readable string

Tags: java, bouncycastle, asn.1

I have a dummy x509 certificate with the following subject

```
Subject: C=.., ST=..., O=..., OU=..., CN=.../emailAddress=123asd@asd.ds
```

The method

```
certificate.getSubjectX500Principal().getName()
```

returns

```
1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=#160d313233617364406173642e6473,CN=...,OU=...,O=...,ST=...,C=...
```

I need to parse this DN to a readable string.

Using bouncycastle I can get the value corresponding to the 1.2.840.113549.1.9.1 key from the symbols map (it's E) but I don't know what to do with this #160d313233617364406173642e6473.

How can I parse this #160d313233617364406173642e6473 to a readable string?

Comment: Why did you decide that it is DERIA5String? It is the HEX representation of some ASN.1 DER-encoded data (actually, the ASN.1 DER representation of the ASN.1 `Name` structure).

Comment: According to http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt the E value is encoded in IA5String to support the @ symbol.

Comment: What is E value? And what do you think is the result of invoking `myString.getBytes("UTF-8")`?

Comment: E is short for email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;    

byte[] data = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(yourHexString);    
ASN1InputStream s = new ASN1InputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
ASN1String str = (ASN1String) s.readObject();
System.out.println(str.getString());
```

Comment: Do I have to get rid of the # first?

Comment: @mzdh yes, you have to remove it